# Como hacer una comparación de fechas en un where, con NodeJs

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js

Estoy tratando de obtener los registros de la fecha actual, el campo que quiero comparar en del tipo date.
Solo quiero que me muestre los registros que se hicieron en el día, mi duda es como puedo comparar campos del tipo date, porque así como tengo este metodo me devuelve todos los resultados.
Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es lo siguiente:

```
const getAll = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getModels()
      .then(models => {
        let OrderModel = models.OrderModel
        let PartnerGroupModel = models.PartnerGroupModel
        let PartnerModel = models.PartnerModel

        let hoy = new Date() //obtengo la fecha de hoy



        OrderModel.findAll({
          attributes: ['int_id', 'int_sequence', 'dtm_requested_date', 'str_reception_hour', 'dtm_aproved_date'],
          where: {dtm_aproved_date: hoy},
          include: [
            { model: PartnerGroupModel },
            { model: PartnerModel },           
          ]
        })
          .then(rows => resolve(rows))
          .catch(err => { throw err })

      })
      .catch(err => reject(`error.orders.models.order. ${err}`))
  })
}
```